# Python line condenser function

Tags: python, iteration

This is a function I just wrote that tries to condense a set of strings into grouped lines. It actually works, but looks ugly. Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

**Take 4** *filtering empty strings first and dropping the `if line` on the final `yield`*

```
def mergeToLines(strings, length=40, sep="    "):
    strs = (st for st in sorted(strings, key=len, reverse=True) if st)
    line = strs.next()
    for s in strs:
        if (len(line) + len(s) + len(sep)) >= length:
            yield line
            line = s
        else:
            line += sep + s
    yield line
```

The idea is that it takes a bunch of strings, and combines them into lines about as long as `lineLength`. Each line has one or more of the original strings in it, but how many isn't clear until I actually get to slotting them in. Also, note that if a single entry in the list is longer than `lineLength`, it's still added as its own line (dropping elements is not an option here).

Comment: In take 3, `if line:` is redundant unless you have empty strings in `strings`. If you do have empty strings, you probably should filter out all of them earlier on.

Comment: @JanneKarila - good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RECURSIVE SOLUTION:**
*NOTE: it assumes that the input `strings` is already sorted. You could sort this at every call of the function, but this seems like unnecessary overhead.*

```
def recursiveMerge(strings=[], current_line='', line_length=40, result=[]):
    """ Gather groups of strings into a line length of approx. 40 """

    # base case
    if not strings:
        result.append(current_line)
        return result

    else:
        next_line = strings.pop(0)

        # if current_line + next_line < line_length, add them
        # otherwise append current_line to result
        if len(current_line + next_line) < line_length:
            current_line = '    '.join([current_line, next_line]).lstrip(' ')    
        else:
            result.append(current_line)
            current_line = next_line

        # recursively call function
        return recursiveMerge(strings, current_line = current_line, result=result)
```

**ITERATIVE SOLUTION:**

```
def myMerge(strings, line_length=40, res=[]):
    """ Gather groups of strings into a line length of approx. 40 """

    # sort the list of string by len
    strings = sorted(strings, key=len, reverse=True)

    # loop through the group of strings, until all have been used
    current_line = strings.pop(0)
    while strings:
        next_line = strings.pop(0)

        # if current_line + next_line shorter than line_length, add them
        # otherwise, append current_line to the result

        if len(current_line + next_line) < line_length:
            current_line = '    '.join([current_line, next_line])
        else:
            res.append(current_line)
            current_line = next_line

    # add any remaining lines to result     
    res.append(current_line)

    return res
```

Comment: l_len should be line_length, no?

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't so ugly, guys :) But I can write it better

```
def cool_merger(strings, line_len=40, sep="    "):
    ss = list(sorted(strings, key=len, reverse=True))
    return [line for line in [(lambda n, s: s if n+1 < len(ss) and (len(s) + len(ss[n+1]) >= line_len) else (ss.__setitem__(n+1, sep.join((str(ss[n]), str(ss[n+1]))))) if len(ss) > n+1 else ss[n] )(n, s) if len(s) < line_len else s for n, s in enumerate(ss)] if line != None]
```

(*joke*)

By the way, works fast.

Comment: +1 for it being crazy short! Very nice. Wouldn't want to be your team-mate who had to maintain it though :)

Comment: @NickBurns Thanks :) Surely it's written not for production but just for fun. Maintainability should be on the first place.